# How do I recover from a faulted zpool where one device is OK, but was temporarily offline?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, freebsd, zfs, raidz

I have a zpool with 4 2TB USB disks in a raidz config:

```
[root@chef /mnt/Chef]# zpool status farcryz1
  pool: farcryz1
 state: ONLINE
 scrub: none requested
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    farcryz1    ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da1     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da2     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da3     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da4     ONLINE       0     0     0
```

In order to test the pool, I simulated a drive failure by pulling the USB cable from one of the drives without taking it offline:

```
[root@chef /mnt/Chef]# zpool status farcryz1
  pool: farcryz1
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an unrecoverable error.  An
    attempt was made to correct the error.  Applications are unaffected.
action: Determine if the device needs to be replaced, and clear the errors
    using 'zpool clear' or replace the device with 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-9P
 scrub: none requested
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    farcryz1    ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da4     ONLINE      22     4     0
        da3     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da1     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da2     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Data's still there, pool still online. Great! Now let's try to restore the pool. I plugged the drive back in, and issued the `zpool replace` command as I was instructed to above:

```
[root@chef /mnt/Chef]# zpool replace farcryz1 da4
invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
/dev/da4 is part of active pool 'farcryz1'
```

Um.... That's not helpful... So I tried a `zpool clear farcryz1`, but that didn't help at all. I still couldn't replace `da4`. So I tried a combination of `online`ing, `offline`ing, `clear`ing, `replace`ing, and `scrub`ing. Now I am stuck here:

```
[root@chef /mnt/Chef]# zpool status -v farcryz1
  pool: farcryz1
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
    invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
    functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
 scrub: scrub completed after 0h2m with 0 errors on Fri Sep  9 13:43:34 2011
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    farcryz1    DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz1    DEGRADED     0     0     0
        da4     UNAVAIL      9     0     0  experienced I/O failures
        da3     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da1     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da2     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
[root@chef /mnt/Chef]# zpool replace farcryz1 da4
cannot replace da4 with da4: da4 is busy
```

How can I recover from this situation, where one device in my zpool was unexpectedly disconnected (but is not a failed device) and is now back again, ready to be resilvered?

---

**EDIT:** As requested, a `tail` of `dmesg`:

```
(ses3:umass-sim4:4:0:1): removing device entry
(da4:umass-sim4:4:0:0): removing device entry
ugen3.2: <Western Digital> at usbus3
umass4: <Western Digital My Book 1140, class 0/0, rev 3.00/10.03, addr 1> on usbus3
da4 at umass-sim4 bus 4 scbus6 target 0 lun 0
da4: <WD My Book 1140 1003> Fixed Direct Access SCSI-6 device 
da4: 400.000MB/s transfers
da4: 1907697MB (3906963456 512 byte sectors: 255H 63S/T 243197C)
ses3 at umass-sim4 bus 4 scbus6 target 0 lun 1
ses3: <WD SES Device 1003> Fixed Enclosure Services SCSI-6 device 
ses3: 400.000MB/s transfers
ses3: SCSI-3 SES Device
GEOM: da4: partition 1 does not start on a track boundary.
GEOM: da4: partition 1 does not end on a track boundary.
GEOM: da4: partition 1 does not start on a track boundary.
GEOM: da4: partition 1 does not end on a track boundary.
ugen3.2: <Western Digital> at usbus3 (disconnected)
umass4: at uhub3, port 1, addr 1 (disconnected)
(da4:umass-sim4:4:0:0): lost device
(da4:umass-sim4:4:0:0): removing device entry
(ses3:umass-sim4:4:0:1): lost device
(ses3:umass-sim4:4:0:1): removing device entry
ugen3.2: <Western Digital> at usbus3
umass4: <Western Digital My Book 1140, class 0/0, rev 3.00/10.03, addr 1> on usbus3
da4 at umass-sim4 bus 4 scbus6 target 0 lun 0
da4: <WD My Book 1140 1003> Fixed Direct Access SCSI-6 device 
da4: 400.000MB/s transfers
da4: 1907697MB (3906963456 512 byte sectors: 255H 63S/T 243197C)
ses3 at umass-sim4 bus 4 scbus6 target 0 lun 1
ses3: <WD SES Device 1003> Fixed Enclosure Services SCSI-6 device 
ses3: 400.000MB/s transfers
ses3: SCSI-3 SES Device
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Determine if the device needs to be replaced, and clear the errors
>   using 'zpool clear' or replace the device with 'zpool replace'.

Looks like after the initial temporary failure, you may only have needed to do a `zpool clear` to clear the errors.

If you want to pretend that it's a drive replacement, you probably need to clear the data off the drive first before you try re-adding it to the pool.

Comment: "you may only have needed to do a zpool clear to clear the errors" -- so the extra commands I ran probably caused the situation I'm in now. I suspected that as well. "you probably need to clear the data off the drive first before you try re-adding it to the pool" -- So, `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/da4 bs=1M`?

Comment: Sure, blow it away, pretend its a brand-new drive.

Comment: This did it, thanks! Before this would work, I had to reboot, and after doing so, `zpool replace farcryz1 da4` responded with `cannot replace da4 with da4: no such pool or dataset`. But hooking up another USB drive as `da4` and then the newly-zeroed 2TB drive after as `da5` allowed me to `zpool replace farcryz1 da4 da5`. Thanks!

Comment: you have to zero the entire drive?

Comment: I was in a similar situation and was able to replace after zeroing without reboot

Answer (score 1):

What were the outputs of the various commands you tried? Did you try the `-f` switch on any of them?

Did you run `zpool clear poolname device-name`?

In your case, `zpool clear farcryz1 da4` - That should have gotten the resilvering process underway.

Comment: I tried `zpool clear farcryz1 da4`, and it produces no output and no change at all. I just did that and I am now seeing `da4     UNAVAIL      3     0     0  experienced I/O failures`.

Comment: And can you reboot? What does a tail of `dmesg` say?

Comment: I can reboot, but have not yet. I will try that, but, should that be necessary? I have added a tail of dmesg but it's not very useful...

Answer (score 1):

If `zpool clear` doesn't fix it, you can make zfs forget the disk using `zpool labelclear <partition>` (available in http://zfsonlinux.org since [zfs-v0.6.2](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/releases/tag/zfs-0.6.2)).

Be aware that even if you created the zpool using a whole device e.g. `/dev/sda` you have to specify the partition which zfs has created, e.g. `/dev/sda1`.

(Credits go to DeHackEd, https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/2076)

From a [zpool manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?zpool(8)):

```
zpool labelclear [-f] device

Removes ZFS label information from the specified device. The device
must not be part of an active pool configuration.

  -f     Treat exported or foreign devices as inactive.
```