How I do recover from an offline, but OK drive on a ZFS mirror?
I have a ZPool consisting in two drives in a mirror configuration. It seems that during server manteinance (cleaning), one of the drives went offline because the wiring came lose.
# zpool status -v zmsmall1
  pool: zmsmall1
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
        invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
        functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 02:00:24 with 0 errors on Sun Apr 14 02:24:25 2024
config:

        NAME                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        zmsmall1                              DEGRADED     0     0     0
          mirror-0                            DEGRADED     0     0     0
            ata-ST1000NM0033-9ZM173_Z1W074QR  ONLINE       0     0     0
            16687432235547222567              UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/disk/by-id/ata-TOSHIBA_MG03ACA100_93S2K8CZF-part1

errors: No known data errors

Unfortunately there was no notification on the problem. After 4 days I detected the problem and now I have doubts on how to proceed.
My concern is that the online drive as been receiving data during this past days and drifted from the 2nd drive status.
I fear that simply bringing back the second drive and issuing a zpool clear zmsmall1 could mess the good data on the first drive.
How I should proceed for a safe recovery?
PS: I'm already doing a second backup, but I would prefer to solve the situation (for practicing) instead of bringing up a new pool.

zpool clear zmsmall1 is the right command.

zfs will start the resilvering process on the disk being brought online and this will go on until the contents of this drive match the contents of the good drive. Application I/O can continue while the resilvering process is going on.

Answers from a similar question that may be helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/309859

Thank you very much. It finally went well as you stated.

I finally took the risk and re-connected the offline drive.
As storsan commented, the pool inmediately changed to an OK state and a resilvering process for the "outdated" drive started inmediately.
The error was still showing in zpool status, but it clearly said that it was all Ok with the pool.
So I issued a zpool clear zmsmall1, the error history cleared and there was no clue that there was an error.
# zpool status zmsmall1
  pool: zmsmall1
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 1.07G in 00:00:40 with 0 errors on Sat May 18 21:10:16 2024
config:

        NAME                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        zmsmall1                              ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                            ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST1000NM0033-9ZM173_Z1W074QR  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-TOSHIBA_MG03ACA100_93S2K8CZF  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors


After more than a month without getting an alternative answer to mark as solution, i'll mark this one.
